# Oracle procedure from a Linux script gives an error

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, sh, sqlplus

**Situation** : I'm trying to run an Oracle Stored procedure from a Linux shell script. I created a .sql file called **my_procedure.sql** as shown below:

```
set serveroutput on
set serveroutput off
DECLARE
    my_variable NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
   exec schema.my_procedure();
END;
/
EXIT
```

The above .sql file is in turn called from a simple shell script called **myscript.sh** like this:

```
sqlplus -s /@connection_sid @my_procedure
```

**Problem**: When I execute `sh myscript.sh`, it throws an error in the my_procedure.sql file as below:

```
Encountered the symbol 'schema' when expecting one of the following
:= . ( @ % ;
```

**What I've tried so far** : I guess-worked by removing the exec keyword. Then I tried using username.schema.myprocedure, but nothing worked.

This procedure runs fine from the command line thus:

```
sqlplus -s username/password <<END
exec myprocedure();
END;
```

Any suggestions for this shall be very helpful.

Comment: What do you mean with "but nothing worked", after removing the `exec`? `exec` is for SQLPlus, and you can not use it within a PlSQL block.

Comment: Removing exec gives the error: "Identifier 'schema.my_procedure' must be declared". Where should it be declared ? I just saved and ran it within the schema.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44283970/7998591

Comment: Kaushik, in my .sql file, neither "exec" nor removing exec worked. Only the error message differed. With "exec", the error message is "Encountered the symbol schema..." and without it, the error message is, "Identifier schema.my_procedure"  must be declared.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
exec schema.my_procedure();
```

in your procedure should be just

```
schema.my_procedure();
```

Comment: Hi Littlefoot. I just tried that but it gives the error:  "Identifier 'schema.my_procedure' must be declared". Where should it be declared ? I just saved and ran it within the schema.

Comment: Does user - which runs the procedure - have `execute` privilege on that procedure? Its owner should grant it directly to you (i.e. not via role).

Comment: Littlefoot, that worked ! I went to Oracle SQL Developer, right clicked on the Procedure, then clicked Grant, searched for the user and granted all rights.

Comment: OK, I'm glad you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. The error message is quite misleading though, and can send one on a wild goose chase, whereas the real issue is about execute privileges.