# ORA-06550: linha 1, column 7: PLS-00201: the identifier 'GETTIMEZONE' must be declared

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, asp.net-core

I created a procedure in ORACLE

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GETTIMEZONE 
    (timeZone IN VARCHAR2,
     cur IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
is
BEGIN
open cur FOR SELECT MLT.description 
                          FROM Master_ISO_TimeZone MI
                          INNER JOIN Master_Language_Translation MLT
                       ON MLT.Language_Translation_Id =
                          MI.Language_Translation_Id
                          WHERE MI.time_zone_id = timeZone;
END GETTIMEZONE;
```

and i´m calling in my .NET api

```
OracleParameter[] param = new OracleParameter[2];
                param[0] = new OracleParameter("timeZone", OracleDbType.Varchar2, timeZoneFromUi, ParameterDirection.Input);
                param[1] = new OracleParameter("cur", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
                Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                Command.CommandText = SP_Constants.GETTIMEZONE;
                Command.Parameters.AddRange(param);
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but I get this error:

> ORA-06550: linha 1, column 7:
> PLS-00201: the identifier 'GETTIMEZONE' must be declared

Comment: I guess  you created the procedure with a different user than you connect in your application. Or you did not grant `EXECUTE` if the user is different.

Comment: Usually when I have a PL/SQL with one input parameter and just one output then I would prefer a FUNCTION: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GETTIMEZONE(timeZone IN VARCHAR2) AS SYS_REFCURSOR IS ...` But maybe that's more a matter of taste.

Comment: Of course, I don't know the content of your tables. However package [UTL_I18N](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_i18n.htm#ARPLS410) may provide the same information in more reliable and consistent way. Just as proposal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PLS-00201 identifier 'PACKAGENAME.PROCEDURENAME' must be declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280921/pls-00201-identifier-packagename-procedurename-must-be-declared)